# Android Studio Start Failed when updated to 4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, startup, failed-installation

I updated my Android Studio to 4.1 and then it gave starting error. I uninstalled and then installed the latest version that is 4.1 again and it still gives the following error on Start up.

```
**Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.loadDescriptors()[Lcom/intellij/ide/plugins/IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl
at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:121)
at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:71)
at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:19)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startApp(StartupUtil.java:303)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:245)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:47)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
JRE 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64 by JetBrains s.r.o
C:\Program Files\Android New\jre\jre**
```

I have tried almost all the solutions on internet but no luck.

Comment: have you done invalidating cache? then restart your project

Comment: Android Studio doesn't even open. How can i invalidate cache?

Comment: have you deleted the previous android studio files manually

Comment: did you try deleting your older config .Android Studio4.0 folder

Comment: Yes deleted them manually. Also deleted the .android folder

Comment: The locations of user configuration directories have been changed for consistency with recent updates to IntelliJ IDEA. check with this

Comment: Where can i find these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this way will work remove this files

C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioPreview4.1
Because there is no Kotlin plugin compatible with Canary 9 currently available from JetBrains, we have bundled our own Kotlin plugin with the Canary 9 update, so you don't need to manually install a Kotlin plugin
see this
https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#4.1-ki-missing-kotlin-plugin

Comment: okay, also make sure you deleted Android files from 
c/program files/Android

Comment: They are also deleted. I deleted almost all the files related to android and now i think i deleted some files that shouldn't be deleted. But still installing new android studio should work.

Comment: download android studio from here

https://developer.android.com/studio?gclid=Cj0KCQjwoJX8BRCZARIsAEWBFMLjWEtaaMNGTt7YdyVh1cYHWHbGtOdBets3-4HgaeKnjJ9FBBAWKvIaAlSfEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: I'm not sure. This is the error that i get: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.loadDescriptors()

Comment: Are you installed kotlin in your device?

Comment: this way will work
remove this files
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioPreview4.1

Because there is no Kotlin plugin compatible with Canary 9 currently available from JetBrains, we have bundled our own Kotlin plugin with the Canary 9 update, so you don't need to manually install a Kotlin plugin

see this 
https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#4.1-ki-missing-kotlin-plugin

Comment: I deleted the .local/google/AndroidStudio.xx file and it started working. Please add in your answer.

Comment: Deleting  .local/google/AndroidStudio.xx folder in ubuntu will work.

Answer (score 6):

For Windows, go to:
`%USERPROFILE%\.AndroidStudio4.0\config\plugins\marketplace`
and remove the `lib` folder

Answer (score 5):

For Ubuntu: please remove the file .local/share/google and Open android studio it will work.

Answer (score 3):

My AndroidStudio 4.1 started after deleting the folder:

> ~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/201.6858069.plugins/marketplace/lib

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.
Version number in the path above may be different.

Comment: Worked for me.

For Windows with JetBrains Toolbox it's
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\AndroidStudio\ch-0\201.6858069.plugins\marketplace

Answer (score 1):

Deleting this folder called `marketplace`, fixed my issue

> C:\Users\UserName.AndroidStudio4.0\config\plugins\marketplace

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the below path works for me

```
C:\Users\username\.AndroidStudio4.0\config\plugins
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by deleting this folder.

> C:\Users"user"\AppData\Roaming\Google

Answer (score 0):

In Linux based Operating Systems like Ubuntu, Linuxmint:

Go to below specified folder by the command:

`cd ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio/`

now rename the folder marketplace as markerplace_backup by the command:

`mv marketplace marketplace_backup`

Now try to open Android Studio again.